# Using UniMRCP integrated with Google TTS

Tags: text-to-speech, unimrcp

I developed an application based on MRCP protocol (using UniMRCP) and now I'm trying to integrate it with google TTS but I'm having some problems. Has anyone tried to develop a TTS plugin for UniMRCP using Google TTS? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I have succesfully integrated google TTS in uniMRCP plugin module.